# Python Insert text before a specific text

Tags: python, html

I want to append a html file(myhtml.html) into an existing html(abc.html) before the footer tag.

Here is the code that I use to do that:

```
with open("abc.html", "r+") as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    print(a)
    index = 0
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith("<footer"):
        
            with open("myhtml.html","r") as f_insert:
                a_insert = [x_insert.rstrip() for x_insert in f_insert]
                
                index_insert = 0
                print(index)
                print(index_insert)
                for item_insert in a_insert:
                    a.insert(index, item_insert) 
                    index +=1
            break
        index += 1
```

This is how the HTML file where I want to append my html file looks:

```
</div></div><footer><div class=container-fl><div class="footer-text"><p class="text-center">
```

You would notice that footer tag is not at start of the line and hence I am not able to append  my html before the footer tag.
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `BeautifulSoup` library.

Comment: Yes I used it but beautiful soup corrupted the graphs in the html that I am appending

Comment: instead of `if item.startswith("<footer"):` have you tried `if "<footer" in item:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a list of lines and don't need to update the input file, then:

```
# read once
with open("myhtml.html","r") as f_insert:
    a_insert = [line.rstrip() for line in f_insert]

with open("abc.html", "r") as f:
    a = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    for i, line in enumerate(a):
        if "<footer" in line:
            a[i:i] = a_insert
            break
```

`a` is the resultant `list`.

However, if you want to update the input file, the following would be more direct:

```
# read once
with open("myhtml.html","r") as f_insert:
    a_insert = f_insert.readlines() # keep whitespace at end

with open("abc.html", "r+") as f:
    a = f.readlines() # keep whitespace at end
    for i, line in enumerate(a):
        if "<footer" in line:
            a[i:i] = a_insert
            break
    f.seek(0, 0) # position to start of file
    for line in a:
        f.write(a)
```